# Live Streaming form a webpage using user camera

Tags: streaming, webrtc, rtmp, getusermedia

I need to stream a live event using the user camera from a web page. My idea is use `getUserMedia()` to get the video from user camera and send it to a RTMP point, it's possible? Or there are another way to do it?

Comment: It is possible if you do a peer connection to some sort of MCU like [the janus-gateway](https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway). This is a rather broad question, btw.

Answer (score 1):

Its possible but for that we have detail knowledge about all encoder and decoders. most of developer trying to do a same thing after flash support drop by Firefox and chrome. Yes, it is possible wowza media server doing same thing check [here](http://www.telestream.net/land/wirecast-wowza.htm)